# How to find click event in forceDirectedGraph in Angular-nvd3 chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

Iam working on Angular-nvd3 **forceDirectedGraph** to show data.

I have plot the chart but unable to trigger click event only in **forceDirectedGraph**.
My issue is when I click on any node i need to open a popup and show data regarding  that node.

I did some research in angular-nvd3 site but was unable to find click event which normally will come like below code:

```
dispatch: {  
                elementMouseover: (t, u)=>{


                },
                elementMouseout: (t, u)=>{


                },
                elementClick: (t, u) =>{

                }
            }
```

And I should bind the data in angular 6 scope or I can call a function to bind it.

Please find the below code which I have worked on and suggest me the right way.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/etWUfV1DxMFoIp3R5tX6?p=streamer)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done within the `nodeExtras` function. When you extend it in your `Plunkr` as shown below, the "stringified" node object is shown in an alert when a mouse click occurs on it. It also changes the cursor (into hand cursor) when the mouse pointer hovers over a node.

```
nodeExtras: function(node) {
      node 
      .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
      .on('click', n => alert(JSON.stringify(n)))
      && node
      .append("text")
      .attr("dx", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".55em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name;})
      .style('font-size', '10px');
},
```

Instead of `'click'`, you will probably rather opt for `'dblclick'`, otherwise the alert is displayed each time the user drags a node.